# Copying images into Mac PowerPoint 2011

Tags: macos, images, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I have an image I've copied into a PowerPoint presentation "content box" or whatever that is. However the aspect ratio between the image and box is not the same, so I selected the option to let PowerPoint automatically resize the image to fit the size of the box.

Now I want to copy-paste this image to a blank slide and rescale it with my mouse to arrange it with other images. However, the content box is pasted along with it and contains a lot of extra space around the image. How can I get rid of this? I would like to get back the original image with bounds that you get when you paste an image directly onto a blank slide.

I no longer have access to the original image I copied, so starting over is not possible.

**Edit:** 
 [Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2125453_remove-placeholders-powerpoint.html#ixzz2LNGFYOpj) it says to "To get an image or text out of a placeholder after it has already been converted, copy and paste it to a new section of the PowerPoint presentation." But it just copies the image with the placeholder.

**Edit 2:** [Here](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/picturesandvisuals/adjust-picture-options-ppt2011-mac.html) it says that there is a reset picture option but this does not change anything once I've Resized picture to fit inside placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

in many such programs, it is possible to select the "content box" (with contents) or just the contents. You have to be careful where you click.

If you look closely, you should be able to see what is selected and be able to see the minute change when you select the content box vs. the contents thereof.

Also, there is a Zoom option. You might try zooming out a lot (25% or 10%) and then making the content box REALLY big, bigger than the content. Then you can more easily and more obviously see the content and select it specifically. Then copy/cut and paste it somewhere else.